# How to Filter user submissions to ASP.Net Web Site for inappropriate content

Tags: c#, asp.net, filter

I am about to publish my restauarnt review web site in which users can submit reivews on local restaurants.  I am interested in suggestions/strategies on how I might develop/acquaire tool(s) that wuuld help filter user text content.  I would like to tag content that is unsuitable (sexually explicit, cursing, etc) and then personally review that content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- You can set submitted posts as draft/non-active, and do not publish immediately. It's called pre-moderation. After moderator checks the content he/she may change the status to active and make it publicly accessible.

2- I would like to suggest you to check the link below for an article which describes about Bad Word Filter With Regular Expressions.

http://weblogs.asp.net/andrewrea/archive/2008/05/03/bad-word-filter-with-regular-expressions.aspx

finally have a look at here

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/showcase/Kentico_CMS.aspx